# Python function pointer

Tags: python, function-pointers

I have a function name stored in a variable like this:

```
myvar = 'mypackage.mymodule.myfunction'
```

and I now want to call myfunction like this

```
myvar(parameter1, parameter2)
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not store the function itself? `myvar = mypackage.mymodule.myfunction` is much cleaner.

Comment: From a comment below: «It must be a string because at the place where it is defined, the application does not know the desired function, since it's a generic app.» – schneck

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
funcdict = {
  'mypackage.mymodule.myfunction': mypackage.mymodule.myfunction,
    ....
}

funcdict[myvar](parameter1, parameter2)
```

Comment: I wonder what the performance hit is here if the function was going to be called a great many times (within a loop, recursion, etc) ?

Comment: The reference is already resolved, so only the lookup within the dict takes any time beyond calling a local function. And even that can be mitigated by only looking up once.

Comment: What is this "mypackage.mymodule.myfunction"? Where can I read more on that?

Comment: @OrvarKorvar: Replace with the name and reference of your choice.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. fundict is a dictionary.

Comment: Of functions, yes.

Answer (score 48):

It's much nicer to be able to just store the function itself, since they're first-class objects in python.

```
import mypackage

myfunc = mypackage.mymodule.myfunction
myfunc(parameter1, parameter2)
```

But, if you have to import the package dynamically, then you can achieve this through:

```
mypackage = __import__('mypackage')
mymodule = getattr(mypackage, 'mymodule')
myfunction = getattr(mymodule, 'myfunction')

myfunction(parameter1, parameter2)
```

Bear in mind however, that all of that work applies to whatever scope you're currently in. If you don't persist them somehow, you can't count on them staying around if you leave the local scope.

Answer (score 19):

```
def f(a,b):
    return a+b

xx = 'f'
print eval('%s(%s,%s)'%(xx,2,3))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 5
```

Comment: I'll give an upvote to counteract the downvote. It may not be the best solution, I do think it's a helpful answer since it shows a complete, working example.

Comment: @zanlok Yes it is! :-) back then I didn't know that.

Comment: @PratikDeoghare iam beginner in python could you explain what (xx = 'f') is doing thanks.

Comment: @RaHuL literally creating a string `xx`. The last line is the most interesting one

Answer (score 13):

Easiest

```
eval(myvar)(parameter1, parameter2)
```

You don't have a function "pointer".  You have a function "name".

While this works well, you will have a large number of folks telling you it's "insecure" or a "security risk".

Comment: "insecure": If myvar comes from user input, yes :)

Comment: Aside from security issues, I get a "NameError: name 'mypackage' is not defined", while I can import modules from there going the "normal" way. And: of course, the string that shall be evaluated is fixed and not changed by the user.

Comment: @schneck, then why would it possibly have to be a string?

Comment: @schneck: If eval('the string') does not produce the correct function, then your question is incomplete.  You've omitted something crucial.  You might try posting something that *does* work along with the detailed error message of what doesn't work.

Comment: @Derrick Turn, @Truptych: They'd be right only if the string came from a malicious sociopath.  User input from unauthenticated people on the internet is likely to involve malicious sociopaths.  Most everything else does not generally involve malicious sociopaths, reducing the security risk to exactly the same risk as someone deleting all the source code for the application.

Comment: It's only insecure if the data comes from external sources. If myvar is defined in your app, it's no less secure that directly calling the function.

Comment: @Mike Graham: It must be a string because at the place where it is defined, the application does not know the desired function, since it's a generic app.

Comment: @schneck, I don't understand what you mean by "since it's a generic app" could mean here. If you have defined this as a string literal, you already know enough about it that you don't need to do so.

Comment: Given the ability to run any functions given in `myvar`, why worry about `eval`?

Comment: @Mike Graham: I thought about that and I think you're right; I should  reference a real function name rather than by a string.

Answer (score 8):

Why not store the function itself? `myvar = mypackage.mymodule.myfunction` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

```
modname, funcname = myvar.rsplit('.', 1)
getattr(sys.modules[modname], funcname)(parameter1, parameter2)
```

Answer (score 4):

`eval(compile(myvar,'<str>','eval'))(myargs)`

compile(...,'eval') allows only a single statement, so that there can't be arbitrary commands after a call, or there will be a SyntaxError. Then a tiny bit of validation can at least constrain the expression to something in your power, like testing for 'mypackage' to start.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem while creating a library to handle authentication. I want the app owner using my library to be able to register a callback with the library for checking authorization against LDAP groups the authenticated person is in. The configuration is getting passed in as a config.py file that gets imported and contains a dict with all the config parameters.

I got this to work:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def target_func(self):
...         print "made it!"
...    
...     def __init__(self,config):
...         self.config = config
...         self.config['funcname'] = getattr(self,self.config['funcname'])
...         self.config['funcname']()
... 
>>> instance = MyClass({'funcname':'target_func'})
made it!
```

Is there a pythonic-er way to do this?