# How can I remove a string's parentheses so it can be used in functions?

Tags: string, function, python-3.x, instance

If I make a function call `check('list')` and in the function that I'm defining, which is called check, I want to use `if isinstance(value, x):` where x is the argument of check, currently `'list'` but it may be any variable type, is there a simple way to use `list` instead of `'list'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2283243/20862).

```
typemap = {
  'list': list
   ...
}

def check(x):
   ...
  if isinstance(value, typemap[x]):
     ...
```

But really you should just be passing `list` directly.

Comment: Uh, no. You would index it as you would any other dictionary. Just as I have shown.